# Which exception handler is handling MissingRequestHeaderException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a large Spring Boot codebase in which I am trying to introduce request header validation.

This is my sample controller:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/abc/test/v1")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/testMethod")
    public String testMethod(@RequestHeader 
            @Size(min = 10, message = "Not valid header") String foo) {
        return foo;
    }

}
```

And this is the `@ControllerAdvice` error handler:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import com.abc.test.exception.RequestParamValidationException;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })  
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping( produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ValidationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<RequestParamValidationException> handleConstraintVoilationexception(ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest req) {
        List<String> details = new LinkedList<>();

        for(ConstraintViolation<?> violation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
            details.add(violation.getMessage());
        }

        RequestParamValidationException exception = new RequestParamValidationException
                ("Request Param Validation Failed", details);

        return new ResponseEntity(exception, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

This is a minimal reproducible example of my project, **but I have no other error handlers present.**

Even though I should be getting a `ConstraintVoilationexception`, but the `MissingRequestHeaderException` keeps being handled by a mysterious error handler which I have not declared, as I can see from my logs:

```
2020-06-08 10:49:10.655  WARN 3180 --- [0.0-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Missing request header 'foo' for method parameter of type String]
```

It never reaches my exception handler.

**How do I find out what is this mysterious exception handler is ?**

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to handle with `ConstraintViolationException` then use  `required=false` for @RequestHeader and use @NotBlank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define order of ValidationExceptionHandler
It's done with annotation `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`

Second, you need to override method because `MissingRequestHeaderException` is subclass of `ServletRequestBindingException`

```java
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleServletRequestBindingException(
        final ServletRequestBindingException ex,
        final HttpHeaders headers,
        final HttpStatus status,
        final WebRequest request
    ) {
        return super.handleServletRequestBindingException(ex, headers, status, request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`MissingRequestHeaderException` is a subclass of `ServletRequestBindingException`.Extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler will automatically give you various methods to handle different exceptions by default.One of the method  is **handleServletRequestBindingException**.

So your MissingRequestHeaderException is handled by the method of **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler**.

If you have to verify, go to the code of ResponseEntityExceptionHandler in your IDE.
Hope this helps.